# Is there any story of Devi like this mentioned in Shakta scriptures?

Tags: scripture, puranas, devi, devi-bhagavata-purana, shakta

We know that there are many sects in Hinduism and also each sect has a supreme deity. In the puranas, sometimes we get to see about the compassionate side of the gods/goddesses.

In the Bhagavata Purana, we have seen the story of Ajamila.
[The story of Ajamila](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1127145.html)

In the Shiva Purana, we get to see the story of Gunanidhi.
[The story of Gunanidhi](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226015.html)

These are present in the Vaishnava and Shaiva puranas.

I wanted to ask that is there any sort of story like the above mentioned ones in Shakta Puranas or Upapuranas or Tantras where we get to see the benign and compassionate side of the supreme devi?

**NOTE:**

**1. I want the story which is similar to the above mentioned ones and not something else. For example- In both the stories, the attendants of the respective deity appear before the Yamadutas when they are about to take the person to Yamaloka.**

**2. The answer can contain quotes from any scripture like Puranas, Upapuranas or Tantras but it would be good if the scripture is a Shakta scripture. Also, multiple stories are welcomed.**

Comment: In the Devi Bhagavata Purana, there are the anecdotes of Satyavrata, Sudarshana & Trishanku.

Comment: Satyavrata was born dumb, so he was abandoned by his parents. He resided in forests where once he saw a wounded boar pass by, followed by a hunter searching for it. While answering the hunter's query, Satyavrata accidentally recited the Vagvija, causing a sudden spurt of intelligence & eloquent speech I him.

Comment: Sudarshana was the elder son of King Dhruvasandhi of Ayodhya but after his father's death, his mother's co-wife called in her father, who then placed Sudarshana's younger half-brother on the throne, causing Sudarshana to go into exile in the ashrams of Bharadvaja. There he accidentally picked up chanting of the Kamavija & had a vision of Bhagavati in dream. Bhagavati caused the princess of Kashi to fall in love with Sudarshana on the eve of her syayamvara, which caused Sudarshana's usurper half-brother's maternal grandfather angry. He was planning to kill the newly-wed Sudarshana but

Comment: Bhagavati Herself manifested in the battlefield & saved Sudarshana. When the king of Kashi found out that among the dead was one who had been conspiring to kill him, he constructed the Durga temple of Kashi out of gratitude.

Comment: Thanks @AnubrataBit . But was Satyavrata initiated into the kamavija? Asking becoz I've heard that these require initiation and since Satyavrata was born dumb has anyone initiated him?

Comment: No. Satyavrata wasn't initiated but it was his destiny. Devi Bhagavata Purana states that before his birth, Satyavrata's father had a brief spat with a rishi, who then cursed Satyavrata to be born dumb. However after his father pleaded, the rishi stated that he would acquire intellect after birth by divine grace.

Comment: Okay thank you for clarifying 